# VFH+ (Vector Field Histogram+) : Is it possible to choose a candidate sector without a set goal point?

Tags: mobile-robot, motion-planning, mapping, c++, vfh

Good day

I am currently implementing the VFH algorithm.

> Is it possible to configure the algorithm such that a reactionary motion is generated at the presence of an obstacle?

I have been able to generate the obstacle map, primary polar histogram and the binary polar histogram.

> How does one prioritize a sector to pass through?

I have seen an implementation in labview where in it is possible to implement a simple vector field histogram path planning without any goal points [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372983F-01/lvrobovi/advanced_vfh/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about VFH, but VFH+ has the ability to just "drive around" without a goal. A very clear explanation of VFH+ can be found [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johannb/Papers/paper73.pdf).
On page 5 they start choosing what direction to move in. I don't know how much of your code you'll be able to reuse, but I hope this helps...